# Property Value getting lost in ASP .Net

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net, class, properties

I have the following code that populates an Equipment Object.  When I call SubmitChanges, the record is successfully added to the table.  However, when I attempt to save the EquipmentID into the property setting, it is getting reset to zero.

```
    SaveProperties(Equipment)      'Save the properties to Equipment object
    dcVehicle.SubmitChanges()      ' Save to database

    EquipmentID = Equipment.EquipmentId      ' To update ViewState, etc.

    Session.Add("EquipmentID", Equipment.EquipmentId)

    'Add record to the Employee Assignment table (link to the Equipment table)
    Me.AddEquipmentEmployee(Equipment, CInt(Session("divid")))
    dcVehicle.SubmitChanges()

    'Add a status record for the piece of Equipment 
    Me.AddEquipmentStatus(Equipment, CInt(Session("divid")))
    dcVehicle.SubmitChanges()
```

In the class I have the following code.  When _Equipment is set to Nothing, then _EquipmentID gets reset from a valid integer back to zero.  The interesting aspect is that I have two other pieces of this application (Vehicle and Trailer) that has the exact same code (except for the Object name itself).  These other two components work as expected. When the EquipmentID is changed to zero, it ends up creating a NULL record in the Equipment table, after the good record has been added.  The second "SubmitChanges" call adds this NULL record to Equipment and adds the record to the EquipmentAssignment table.

```
'**********************************************
'* Equipment Section                          *
'**********************************************

Private _Equipment As Equipment
Private _EquipmentID As Integer = 0

Public Property EquipmentID() As Integer
    Get
        Integer.TryParse(ViewState("EquipmentID"), _EquipmentID)
        Return _EquipmentID
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As Integer)
        Me.ViewState("EquipmentId") = value
        _EquipmentID = value
        _Equipment = Nothing
    End Set
End Property

Public Property Equipment() As Equipment
    Get
        If _Equipment Is Nothing Then
            _Equipment = dcVehicle.GetEquipment(EquipmentID)
        End If
        Return _Equipment
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As Equipment)
        _Equipment = value
        If value Is Nothing Then
            _EquipmentID = 0
            Me.ViewState("EquipmentID") = 0
        Else
            _EquipmentID = value.EquipmentId
            Me.ViewState("EquipmentID") = value.EquipmentId
        End If
    End Set
End Property
```

Comment: Is "EquipmentId" in line 7 of your second code snippet supposed to be in different case from the others?

Comment: No, it was not supposed to be in a different case.  I am still learning ASP .Net and didn't realize that ViewState was case sensitive.  I made the change and it is now working.  Justin Ryan, thank you SO much!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Per [this Meta post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1555/mark-a-comment-as-answer-to-a-question), I'll post my comment as an answer, so you can tick your question as solved.*

[ViewState](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.viewstate(v=vs.110).aspx) is case sensitive. Line 7 in your second code snippet,

```
    Me.ViewState("EquipmentId") = value
```

should read:

```
    Me.ViewState("EquipmentID") = value
```

Comment: Understand that ViewState is case sensitive, but why would that give me the results I was getting?

Comment: The way I'm reading your code, that would be because although you are setting the correct value to `EquipmentId` (lowercase), when you go to retrieve it as `EquipmentID` (uppercase), that state doesn't exist or returns no value and either TryParse returns it as zero, or it is defaulting to zero, because that's how you initially declared `_EquipmentID`.